# Understanding how CodePen's IDE works with a 2d shooter

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I made a very basic 2d shooter with all the code in 1 single html file: ([file_gist](https://gist.github.com/DravionV/86229d7c48095b36c9cd6caf970759f4)). Everything works exactly as I intended it to when I open the file in my native chrome browser. However when I copied the code and placed the corresponding HTML/CSS/JS into the appropriate fields of the IDE codepen, the program does not behave as intended. I can see that the JS is working by use of the visual text indications ive built into the program, but the animation of the square moving up, down left or right based on keyboard input wont animate. Neither will the 'bullets' animate as intended either. Was wondering how the IDE is interpreting the code differently than my native browser and how to fix this issue.

I think the issue may have to do with the following line of code but im not sure:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);
```

([Pen](https://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/KoGvwj))

Comment: Are there errors in the console? Are you focusing the document before typing?

Comment: I would highly advise doing this in the HTML 5 Canvas, the default DOM isn't really intended for games.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes I am aware of that, I still wanted to write it in the default DOM anyway.

Comment: @espascarello No errors in console that I saw.

Comment: I believe @Veehmot found the issue though. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it works in your end, but for changing `top` and `left`, you need to append the unit, in this case `px`.

So instead of `player.style.left = playerLeft;`, do `player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVPvMJ

Comment: Hmm that worked. Wonder why my browser allowed my version to work then? Thx though - its working as intended now.